# What is causing 0 and 1 to be written to the end of the new file? C++

Tags: c++, getline

I use two different txt files at work for a task. One of them gets updated any time I need to call someone back (callback.txt), and one that gets updated with all of the callbacks that didn't get finished by the end of the day (recap.txt). I have written a basic python program, as well as a PowerShell script, that updates recap.txt at the end of the day by adding the newest entries to the top of the recap.txt from the day before.

Now, I am trying to write it in C++ just to get some experience with the language, but I can't seem to find why I am running into this issue. Everything works as intended, except that "recapNEW.txt" has 0 and 1 written and the end of the file on separate lines each. For example:

```
callback.txt:
  ----------
    here's something
    here is something else
    yadda yadda


recapOLD.txt
  ----------
    old news
    still need it though
    so we keep it around


recapNEW.txt (blank)
  ----------
```

And, after running the program:

```
recapNEW:
  ----------
    here's something
    here is something else
    yadda yadda
    old news
    still need it though
    so we keep it around
    0
    1
```

This is what I have written:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>


void update () {

    std::ifstream callback("callback.txt");
    std::ifstream recapBAK("recapBAK.txt");
    std::ofstream recapNEW("recapNEW.txt");

    std::string callLine;
    std::string bakLine;

    if (!callback || !recapNEW || !recapBAK) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open needed files. Exiting.";
        std::exit(1);
        }

    while (std::getline ( callback,callLine )) {
        recapNEW << callLine << std::endl ;
        }

    while (std::getline ( recapBAK,bakLine )) {
    recapNEW << bakLine << std::endl ;
    }

    recapNEW <<  callback << std::endl << recapNEW << std::endl ;

    callback.close();
    recapBAK.close();
    recapNEW.close();
}
```

I split the recap.txt file into two separate files ("recapBAK.txt" & "recapNEW.txt") to keep a copy of the previous day's recap and am updating it in a separate function (posted below), but I have narrowed it down that it is the above function that is writing the extra numbers to the end of the file.

```
void backup () {

    std::ofstream backup("recapBAK.txt");
    std::ifstream today("recapNEW.txt");

    std::string todayLine;

    while (std::getline (today,todayLine)) {
        backup << todayLine << std::endl;
    }

    backup.close();
    today.close();

}
```

What is confusing me the most is that I don't see what I am doing differently in the first function that is causing the integers to be tagged on to the end of the file, because no additional integers are added to the updated version of recapUSED.

Apologies if this is not clear enough, first time I've hit a wall hard enough that I  posted to a forum lol. I appreciate the help, I'm self-teaching and love having input to work with to see where I can/should improve.

Comment: If you made a [mre] it'd be possible to answer in seconds which would help you faster.

Comment: And because the asker only serves to get the ball rolling, an easily comprehended example with clear cause and effect will help future askers more effectively.

Comment: To copy the contexts of one file into another, use `backup << today.rdbuf();`. `rdbuf()` returns a pointer to the stream's input buffer; output streams have an overloaded inserter (`operator<<`) that copies the buffer to the stream.

Comment: Also, you don't have to call `stream.close();` at the end of your functions. The stream's destructor will do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that in:

```
recapNEW <<  callback << std::endl << recapNEW << std::endl ;
```

... you are attempting to output the contents of the streams `callback` and `recapNEW` to `recapNEW`, but it doesn't work that way. Rather, the Boolean "good" status of the file streams is output instead. Prepending to a stream isn't that simple.

Actually, it looks like you have what you need without that line. Have you tried just removing it?

Comment: Tried without that line and it worked beautifully. Thank you so much for that! I hadn't even considered that the 1 and 0 were pretty obvious signs that it was Boolean values lol.